# Python method variable not updating

Tags: python, variables

Okay, so I've been struggling with this for hours and I cant find an explanation. I have a method:

```
def solvecheck(self, *args):
        for x in range(9):
            for y in range(9):
                if self.grid[y][x] == 0:
                    for n in range(1,10):
                        if self.possible(y,x,n):
                            self.grid[y][x] = n
                            self.solvecheck()
                            self.grid[y][x] = 0
                    return
        grid = self.grid
        print(grid)
        self.check(grid)
```

It's a sudoku solver. This method should just solve the grid. I know it works. So now when I insert the solved grid into the check method:

```
def check(self, grid):

        self.update_grid()

        print(grid)
        print(self.grid)

        if self.grid == grid:
            error = False
        else: error = True
        print(error)

        self.load_grid()
```

This should work right? Wrong. I get the output:

```
[[8, 7, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 2], [1, 6, 5, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4], [9, 2, 4, 7, 6, 3, 1, 8, 5], [4, 8, 9, 6, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1], [7, 5, 2, 8, 3, 1, 6, 4, 9], [3, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 2, 7], [6, 9, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 5, 3], [2, 3, 8, 1, 5, 7, 4, 9, 6], [5, 4, 7, 3, 9, 6, 2, 1, 8]]
[[8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4], [0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5], [0, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9], [0, 0, 6, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
[[8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4], [0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5], [0, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9], [0, 0, 6, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
False
```

The first line being the solved grid. The second line should just be the same line again, right? I don't get why its not. I've tried everything. It displays the same grid, as described in the init method. Why does this happen?

Comment: That code pattern reminds me of 'KameHaMeHa'

Comment: What does self.update_grid?

Comment: It seems self.update_grid() changed the solved grid to it's unsolved grid.

Comment: @JonathanSánchez it updates the self.grid, by matching it to the inputs from the GUI

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your think `grid = self.grid` copy the self.grid to grid. But it doesn't, both grid and self.grid point to the same grid.

Comment: but why does the update grid change the solved grid. in the check method the solved and the unsolved grid have nothing to do with eachother, right?

Comment: Does that mean that when you check the solved grid, you're updating your self.grid again to the inputs from the GUI? I mean, that's not what you want for sure.

Comment: Okay so now I've created a new variable, with the same unsolved grid. Now I get an endless output loop.

Comment: Try `grid = [row[:] for row in self.grid]` instead of `grid = self.grid`

Comment: What happens if you comment `self.update_grid`?

Comment: My goal is to check if the solved grid matches the unsolved one. So It's a "check for errors" button

Comment: I tried @Frank s approach. It works. It crashes afterwards though

Comment: Without functions detail / error detail, can't tell what's wrong. Check your other functions.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't solve anything. There is no algorithm here. You should rather try to use a recursive method and organize all the code in a class. The function should start analyzing vertical, horizontal, and section cells from top left, and keep on going until it reaches bottom right. This should do it.

Comment: i thought that was what I am doing

Comment: it is recursive, isnt it?

Comment: It is not recursive as it starts after a certain number of iterations. Also you're missing a very important game rule that may also be the reason your function isn't working; You're not checking the current section! For every iteration you should check all the cells vertically, horizontally and in the same section. Do you want me to write the function for you?

Comment: A helpful resource to better know what you're doing is to compare your code to someone else's successful code. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM&t=179s might help you out.